# Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Raster

Tags: actionscript-3, compiler-errors, flashdevelop

This is the full error message:

```
C:\Project Files\Good\src\views\RasterView.as(26): col: 39 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Raster.
C:\Project Files\Good\src\views\RasterView.as(42): col: 45 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Raster.
C:\Project Files\Good\src\views\RasterView.as(47): col: 45 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Raster.
C:\Project Files\Good\src\views\RasterView.as(62): col: 32 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Raster.
```

This is the file(it is huge)

```
package views 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import views.Canvas.Raster;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Arthur Wulf White
     */
    public class RasterView extends Bitmap
    {   
        import views.Canvas.Raster

        public static const SCHEMATIC   : int = 1;
        public static const SMOOTH      : int = 2;
        public static const RENDER_ONCE : int = 4;
        public static const BOTH        : int = SCHEMATIC + SMOOTH;

//      protected var bitmapData : Raster;
        protected var viewMode : int = 0;

        protected var lineColor : int = 0xff000000;
        protected var fillColor : int = 0xff808080;
        protected var bgColor   : int = 0xffffffff;

        public function RasterView(raster : Raster) 
        {
            this.bitmapData = raster;
        }

        public function getStyle():Vector.<int>
        {
            return new <int> [lineColor, fillColor, bgColor];
        }
        public function setStyle(lineColor : int, fillColor : int, bgColor : int):void
        {
            this.lineColor  = lineColor;
            this.fillColor  = fillColor;
            this.bgColor    = bgColor;
        }

        public function backupView(backupRaster : Raster):void
        {
            backupRaster.copyPixels(bitmapData, bitmapData.rect, new Point());
        }

        public function loadBackup(backupRaster : Raster):void
        {
            bitmapData.copyPixels(backupRaster, backupRaster.rect, new Point());
        }

        public function getViewMode():int
        {
            return viewMode;
        }

        public function setViewMode(mode : int):void
        {
            viewMode = mode;
        }

        public function get Raster():Raster
        {
            return Raster(bitmapData);
        }

        public function refreshView():void
        {
            bitmapData.lock()
            render();
            bitmapData.unlock();
            if ((getViewMode() & RENDER_ONCE) != 0)
            {
                setViewMode( getViewMode() ^ RENDER_ONCE);
            }
        }

        public function render():void
        {

        }

        protected function clear():void
        {
            bitmapData.fillRect(bitmapData.rect, bgColor);
        }

    }

}
```

This is the file for the Raster class(I don't think it is important for this issue)

```
/**
*
*   Raster class
*   
*   @author     Didier Brun aka Foxy - www.foxaweb.com
*   @version        1.4
*   @date       2006-01-06
*   @link       http://www.foxaweb.com
* 
*   AUTHORS ******************************************************************************
* 
*   authorName :    Didier Brun - www.foxaweb.com
*   contribution :  the original class
*   date :          2007-01-07
* 
*   authorName :    Drew Cummins - http://blog.generalrelativity.org
*   contribution :  added bezier curves
*   date :          2007-02-13
* 
*   authorName :    Thibault Imbert - http://www.bytearray.org
*   contribution :  Raster now extends BitmapData, performance optimizations
*   date :          2009-10-16
* 
*   PLEASE CONTRIBUTE ? http://www.bytearray.org/?p=67
* 
*   DESCRIPTION **************************************************************************
* 
*   Raster is an AS3 Bitmap drawing library. It provide some functions to draw directly 
*   into BitmapData instance.
*
*   LICENSE ******************************************************************************
* 
*   This class is under RECIPROCAL PUBLIC LICENSE.
*   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/rpl.php
* 
*   Please, keep this header and the list of all authors
* 
*/
package views.Canvas
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class Raster extends BitmapData
    {
        private var shape : Shape = new Shape();
        private var buffer:Array = new Array();
        private var r:Rectangle = new Rectangle();

        public function Raster ( width:uint, height:uint, transparent:Boolean=false, color:uint=0)
        {       
            super ( width, height, transparent, color);
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------
        //
        // ---o public methods
        //
        // ------------------------------------------------

        public function setPoint( p : Point, color : int, size : int = 1):void
        {
            if(size == 1)
                setPixel(p.x, p.y, color);
            else if (size > 1)
                drawRect(new Rectangle(p.x - size / 2, p.y - size / 2, size, size), color);
        }

        public function lineAA( x0:int, y0:int, x1:int, y1:int, color:uint ):void
        {
            var i : int = 0;
            var cInt : int;
            var cNum : Number;
            var div  : Number;

            var dx : int = Math.abs(x1 - x0);
            var dy : int = Math.abs(y1 - y0);

            if(dx >= dy)
            {
                //do x
                if (x0 < x1)
                {
                    cInt = x0;
                    cNum = y0;
                }
                else
                {
                    cInt = x1;
                    cNum = y1;
                }

                div = Number(y1 - y0) / Number(x1 - x0);
                setPixel32(cInt, cNum, color);
                for (; i <= dx; i++)
                {
                    cInt++;
                    cNum += div;
                    setAAPixel(cInt, cNum, color, true, false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //do y
                if (y0 < y1)
                {
                    cInt = y0;
                    cNum = x0;
                }
                else
                {
                    cInt = y1;
                    cNum = x1;
                }

                div = Number(x1 - x0) / Number(y1 - y0);
                setPixel32(cNum, cInt, color);
                for (; i <= dy; i++)
                {
                    cInt++;
                    cNum += div;
                    setAAPixel(cNum, cInt, color, false, true);
                }
            }
        }

        public function quadLine(x0 : int, y0 : int, cx : int, cy : int, x1 : int, y1 : int, color : int = 0xff0000ff, detail : int = 20):void
        {
            var epsilon : Number = 1.0 / Number(detail);
            var total : Number = 0;
            var x : int = 0;
            var y : int = 0;
            for (; total <= 1.001; total+=epsilon)
            {
                x = (1 - total) * ((1 - total) * x0 + total * cx) + total * (total * x1 + (1 - total) * cx); 
                y = (1 - total) * ((1 - total) * y0 + total * cy) + total * (total * y1 + (1 - total) * cy);
                setPixel32(x, y, color);
            }
        }
         /**
         * Draws a antialias Quadratic Bezier Curve (equivalent to a DisplayObject's graphics#curveTo)
         * 
         * @param x0            x position of first anchor
         * @param y0            y position of first anchor
         * @param x1            x position of control point
         * @param y1            y position of control point
         * @param x2            x position of second anchor
         * @param y2            y position of second anchor
         * @param c             color
         * @param resolution    [optional] determines the accuracy of the curve's length (higher number = greater accuracy = longer process)
         * */

        public function aaQuadBezier ( anchorX0:int, anchorY0:int, controlX:int, controlY:int, anchorX1:int, anchorY1:int, c:Number, resolution:int = 3):void
        {   
            shape.graphics.clear();
            shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, c, 1);
            shape.graphics.moveTo(anchorX0, anchorY0);
            shape.graphics.curveTo(controlX, controlY, anchorX1, anchorY1);
            this.draw(shape);
        }

        /**
        * Draw an anti-aliased line
        * 
        * @param x0     first point x coord
        * @param y0     first point y coord 
        * @param x1     second point x coord
        * @param y1     second point y coord
        * @param c      color (0xaarrvvbb)
        */
        public function aaLine2( x1:int, y1:int, x2:int, y2:int, color:uint ):void
        {   
            shape.graphics.clear();
            shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, color, 1);
            shape.graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
            shape.graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);
            this.draw(shape);
        }

        /**
        * Draw a line
        * 
        * @param x0     first point x coord
        * @param y0     first point y coord 
        * @param x1     second point x coord
        * @param y1     second point y coord
        * @param c      color (0xaarrvvbb)
        */
        public function line ( x0:int, y0:int, x1:int, y1:int, color:uint ):void
        {   
            var dx:int;
            var dy:int;
            var i:int;
            var xinc:int;
            var yinc:int;
            var cumul:int;
            var x:int;
            var y:int;
            x = x0;
            y = y0;
            dx = x1 - x0;
            dy = y1 - y0;
            xinc = ( dx > 0 ) ? 1 : -1;
            yinc = ( dy > 0 ) ? 1 : -1;
            dx = dx < 0 ? -dx : dx;
            dy = dy < 0 ? -dy : dy;
            setPixel32(x,y,color);

            if ( dx > dy )
            {
                cumul = dx >> 1;
                for ( i = 1 ; i <= dx ; ++i )
                {
                    x += xinc;
                    cumul += dy;
                    if (cumul >= dx)
                    {
                        cumul -= dx;
                        y += yinc;
                    }
                    setPixel32(x,y,color);
                }
            }else
            {
                cumul = dy >> 1;
                for ( i = 1 ; i <= dy ; ++i )
                {
                    y += yinc;
                    cumul += dx;
                    if ( cumul >= dy )
                    {
                        cumul -= dy;
                        x += xinc ;
                    }
                    setPixel32(x,y,color);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
        * Draw a triangle
        * 
        * @param x0     first point x coord
        * @param y0     first point y coord 
        * @param x1     second point x coord
        * @param y1     second point y coord
        * @param x2     third point x coord
        * @param y2     third point y coord
        * @param c      color (0xaarrvvbb)
        */

        public function triangle ( x0:int, y0:int, x1:int, y1:int, x2:int, y2:int, color:uint ):void
        {
            line (x0,y0,x1,y1,color);
            line (x1,y1,x2,y2,color);
            line (x2,y2,x0,y0,color);
        }

        /**
        * Draw a filled triangle
        * 
        * @param x0     first point x coord
        * @param y0     first point y coord 
        * @param x1     second point x coord
        * @param y1     second point y coord
        * @param x2     third point x coord
        * @param y2     third point y coord
        * @param c      color (0xaarrvvbb)
        */
        public function filledTri ( x0:int, y0:int, x1:int, y1:int, x2:int, y2:int, color:uint ):void
        {
            buffer.length = 0;
            lineTri (buffer,x0,y0,x1,y1,color);
            lineTri (buffer,x1,y1,x2,y2,color);
            lineTri (buffer,x2,y2,x0,y0,color);
        }

        /**
        * Draw a circle
        * 
        * @param px     first point x coord
        * @param py     first point y coord 
        * @param r      radius
        * @param c      color (0xaarrvvbb)
        */
        public function circle ( px:int, py:int, r:int, color:uint ):void
        {
            var x:int;
            var y:int;
            var d:int;
            x = 0;
            y = r;
            d = 1-r;
            setPixel32(px+x,py+y,color);
            setPixel32(px+x,py-y,color);
            setPixel32(px-y,py+x,color);
            setPixel32(px+y,py+x,color);

            while ( y > x )
            {
                if ( d < 0 )
                {
                    d += (x+3) << 1;
                }else
                {
                    d += ((x - y) << 1) + 5;
                    y--;
                }
                x++;
                setPixel32(px+x,py+y,color);
                setPixel32(px-x,py+y,color);
                setPixel32(px+x,py-y,color);
                setPixel32(px-x,py-y,color);
                setPixel32(px-y,py+x,color);
                setPixel32(px-y,py-x,color);
                setPixel32(px+y,py-x,color);
                setPixel32(px+y,py+x,color);
            }
        }

        /**
        * Draw an anti-aliased circle
        * 
        * @param px     first point x coord
        * @param py     first point y coord 
        * @param r      radius
        * @param c      color (0xaarrvvbb)
        */
        public function aaCircle ( px:int, py:int, r:int, color:uint ):void
        {
            var vx:int;
            var vy:int;
            var d:int;
            vx = r;
            vy = 0;

            var t:Number=0;
            var dry:Number;
            var buff:int;

            setPixel(px+vx,py+vy,color);
            setPixel(px-vx,py+vy,color);
            setPixel(px+vy,py+vx,color);
            setPixel(px+vy,py-vx,color);

            while ( vx > vy+1 )
            {
                vy++;
                buff = Math.sqrt(r*r-vy*vy)+1;
                dry = buff - Math.sqrt(r*r-vy*vy);
                if (dry<t) vx--;

                drawAlphaPixel(px+vx,py+vy,1-dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px+vx-1,py+vy,dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px-vx,py+vy,1-dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px-vx+1,py+vy,dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px+vx,py-vy,1-dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px+vx-1,py-vy,dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px-vx,py-vy,1-dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px-vx+1,py-vy,dry,color)

                drawAlphaPixel(px+vy,py+vx,1-dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px+vy,py+vx-1,dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px-vy,py+vx,1-dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px-vy,py+vx-1,dry,color)

                drawAlphaPixel(px+vy,py-vx,1-dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px+vy,py-vx+1,dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px-vy,py-vx,1-dry,color)
                drawAlphaPixel(px-vy,py-vx+1,dry,color)

                t=dry;
            }
        }

        /**
        * Draw an anti-aliased line
        * 
        * @param x0     first point x coord
        * @param y0     first point y coord 
        * @param x1     second point x coord
        * @param y1     second point y coord
        * @param c      color (0xaarrvvbb)
        */
        public function aaLine ( x1:int, y1:int, x2:int, y2:int, color:uint ):void
        {   
            var steep:Boolean = Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1);
            var swap:int;

            if (steep)
            {
                swap=x1; x1=y1; y1=swap;
                swap=x2; x2=y2; y2=swap;
            }

            if (x1 > x2)
            {
                swap=x1; x1=x2; x2=swap;
                swap=y1; y1=y2; y2=swap;
            }

            var dx:int = x2 - x1;
            var dy:int = y2 - y1

            var gradient:Number = dy / dx;

            var xend:int = x1;
            var yend:Number = y1 + gradient * (xend - x1);
            var xgap:Number = 1-((x1 + 0.5)%1);
            var xpx1:int = xend;
            var ypx1:int = yend;
            var alpha:Number;

            alpha = ((yend)%1) * xgap;

            var intery:Number = yend + gradient;

            xend = x2;
            yend = y2 + gradient * (xend - x2)
            xgap = (x2 + 0.5)%1;

            var xpx2:int = xend; 
            var ypx2:int = yend;

            alpha = (1-((yend)%1)) * xgap;

            if (steep)
                drawAlphaPixel(ypx2,xpx2,alpha,color);
            else drawAlphaPixel(xpx2, ypx2,alpha,color);

            alpha = ((yend)%1) * xgap;

            if (steep)
                drawAlphaPixel(ypx2 + 1,xpx2,alpha,color);
            else drawAlphaPixel(xpx2, ypx2 + 1,alpha,color);

            var x:int=xpx1;

            while (x++<xpx2)
            {
                alpha = 1-((intery)%1);

                if (steep)
                    drawAlphaPixel(intery,x,alpha,color);
                else drawAlphaPixel(x,intery,alpha,color);

                alpha=intery%1;

                if (steep)
                    drawAlphaPixel(intery+1,x,alpha,color);
                else drawAlphaPixel(x,intery+1,alpha,color);

                intery = intery + gradient
            }
        }

        /**
         * Draws a Rectangle
         * 
         * @param rect          Rectangle dimensions
         * @param color         color
         * */
        public function drawRect ( rect:Rectangle, color:uint ):void
        {
            line ( rect.x, rect.y, rect.x+rect.width, rect.y, color );
            line ( rect.x+rect.width, rect.y, rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height, color );
            line ( rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height, rect.x, rect.y+rect.height, color );
            line ( rect.x, rect.y+rect.height, rect.x, rect.y, color );
        }

        /**
         * Draws a rounded Rectangle
         * 
         * @param rect          Rectangle dimensions
         * @param ellipseWidth  Rectangle corners width
         * @param color         color
         * */
        public function drawRoundRect ( rect:Rectangle, ellipseWidth:int, color:uint ):void
        {
            var arc:Number = 4/3 * (Math.sqrt(2) - 1);
            var xc:Number = rect.x+rect.width-ellipseWidth;
            var yc:Number = rect.y+ellipseWidth;
            line( rect.x+ellipseWidth, rect.y, xc, rect.y, color );
            cubicBezier(xc, rect.y, xc + ellipseWidth*arc, yc - ellipseWidth, xc + ellipseWidth, yc - ellipseWidth*arc, xc + ellipseWidth, yc, color);
            xc = rect.x+rect.width-ellipseWidth;
            yc = rect.y+rect.height-ellipseWidth;
            line( xc + ellipseWidth, rect.y+ellipseWidth, rect.x+rect.width, yc, color );
            cubicBezier(rect.x+rect.width, yc, xc + ellipseWidth, yc + ellipseWidth*arc, xc + ellipseWidth*arc, yc + ellipseWidth, xc, yc + ellipseWidth, color);
            xc = rect.x+ellipseWidth;
            yc = rect.y+rect.height-ellipseWidth;
            line( rect.x+rect.width-ellipseWidth, rect.y+rect.height, xc, yc + ellipseWidth, color );
            cubicBezier( xc, yc + ellipseWidth, xc - ellipseWidth*arc, yc + ellipseWidth, xc - ellipseWidth, yc + ellipseWidth*arc, xc - ellipseWidth, yc, color );
            xc = rect.x+ellipseWidth;
            yc = rect.y+ellipseWidth;
            line( xc - ellipseWidth, rect.y+rect.height-ellipseWidth, rect.x, yc, color );
            cubicBezier(rect.x, yc, xc - ellipseWidth, yc - ellipseWidth*arc, xc - ellipseWidth*arc, yc - ellipseWidth, xc, yc - ellipseWidth, color);
        }

        /**
         * Draws a Quadratic Bezier Curve (equivalent to a DisplayObject's graphics#curveTo)
         * 
         * @param x0            x position of first anchor
         * @param y0            y position of first anchor
         * @param x1            x position of control point
         * @param y1            y position of control point
         * @param x2            x position of second anchor
         * @param y2            y position of second anchor
         * @param c             color
         * @param resolution    [optional] determines the accuracy of the curve's length (higher number = greater accuracy = longer process)
         * */
        public function quadBezier ( anchorX0:int, anchorY0:int, controlX:int, controlY:int, anchorX1:int, anchorY1:int, c:Number, resolution:int = 3):void
        {   
            var ox:Number = anchorX0;
            var oy:Number = anchorY0;
            var px:int;
            var py:int;
            var dist:Number = 0;

            var inverse:Number = 1 / resolution;
            var interval:Number;
            var intervalSq:Number;
            var diff:Number;
            var diffSq:Number;

            var i:int = 0;

            while( ++i <= resolution )
            {
                interval = inverse * i;
                intervalSq = interval * interval;
                diff = 1 - interval;
                diffSq = diff * diff;

                px = diffSq * anchorX0 + 2 * interval * diff * controlX + intervalSq * anchorX1;
                py = diffSq * anchorY0 + 2 * interval * diff * controlY + intervalSq * anchorY1;

                dist += Math.sqrt( ( px - ox ) * ( px - ox ) + ( py - oy ) * ( py - oy ) );

                ox = px;
                oy = py;
            }

            //approximates the length of the curve
            var curveLength:int = dist;
            inverse = 1 / curveLength;

            var lastx:int=anchorX0;
            var lasty:int=anchorY0;

            i = -1;
            while( ++i <= curveLength )
            {
                interval = inverse * i;
                intervalSq = interval * interval;
                diff = 1 - interval;
                diffSq = diff * diff;

                px = diffSq * anchorX0 + 2 * interval * diff * controlX + intervalSq * anchorX1;
                py = diffSq * anchorY0 + 2 * interval * diff * controlY + intervalSq * anchorY1;

                line(lastx,lasty,px,py,c);
                //aaLine(lastx, lasty, px, py, c);
                lastx = px;
                lasty = py;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Draws a Cubic Bezier Curve
         * 
         * TODO: Determine whether x/y params would be better named as anchor/control
         * 
         * @param x0            x position of first anchor
         * @param y0            y position of first anchor
         * @param x1            x position of control point
         * @param y1            y position of control point
         * @param x2            x position of second control point
         * @param y2            y position of second control point
         * @param x3            x position of second anchor
         * @param y3            y position of second anchor
         * @param c             color
         * @param resolution    [optional] determines the accuracy of the curve's length (higher number = greater accuracy = longer process)
         * */
        public function cubicBezier ( x0:int, y0:int, x1:int, y1:int, x2:int, y2:int, x3:int, y3:int, c:Number, resolution:int = 5 ):void
        {
            var ox:Number = x0;
            var oy:Number = y0;
            var px:int;
            var py:int;
            var dist:Number = 0;

            var inverse:Number = 1 / resolution;
            var interval:Number;
            var intervalSq:Number;
            var intervalCu:Number;
            var diff:Number;
            var diffSq:Number;
            var diffCu:Number;
            var i:int = 0;

            while( ++i <= resolution )
            {
                interval = inverse * i;
                intervalSq = interval * interval;
                intervalCu = intervalSq * interval;
                diff = 1 - interval;
                diffSq = diff * diff;
                diffCu = diffSq * diff;

                px = diffCu * x0 + 3 * interval * diffSq * x1 + 3 * x2 * intervalSq * diff + x3 * intervalCu;
                py = diffCu * y0 + 3 * interval * diffSq * y1 + 3 * y2 * intervalSq * diff + y3 * intervalCu;

                dist += Math.sqrt( ( px - ox ) * ( px - ox ) + ( py - oy ) * ( py - oy ) );

                ox = px;
                oy = py;
            }

            //approximates the length of the curve
            var curveLength:int = dist;
            inverse = 1 / curveLength;

            var lastx:int=x0;
            var lasty:int=y0;

            i = -1;

            while( ++i <= curveLength )
            {
                interval = inverse * i;
                intervalSq = interval * interval;
                intervalCu = intervalSq * interval;
                diff = 1 - interval;
                diffSq = diff * diff;
                diffCu = diffSq * diff;

                px = diffCu * x0 + 3 * interval * diffSq * x1 + 3 * x2 * intervalSq * diff + x3 * intervalCu;
                py = diffCu * y0 + 3 * interval * diffSq * y1 + 3 * y2 * intervalSq * diff + y3 * intervalCu;

                line(lastx,lasty,px,py,c);
                lastx = px;
                lasty = py;
            }
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------
        //
        // ---o private static methods
        //
        // ------------------------------------------------

        /**
        * Draw an AA pixel
        */
        private function setAAPixel (x:Number, y:Number, c:Number, roundX : Boolean = false, roundY : Boolean = false):void
        {   
            var xpos    : Number = Math.floor(x);
            var ypos    : Number = Math.floor(y);
            var xA      : Number = x - xpos;
            var yA      : Number = y - ypos;
            if (!roundX && !roundY)
            {
                drawAlphaPixel(xpos     , ypos      , (1 - xA) * (1 - yA)   , c);
                drawAlphaPixel(xpos + 1 , ypos      , xA * (1 - yA)         , c);
                drawAlphaPixel(xpos     , ypos + 1  , (1 - xA) * yA         , c);
                drawAlphaPixel(xpos + 1 , ypos + 1  , xA * yA               , c);
            }
            else if (roundX && !roundY)
            {
                drawAlphaPixel(xpos     , ypos      , (1 - yA)              , c);
                drawAlphaPixel(xpos     , ypos + 1  , yA                    , c);
            }
            else if (roundY && !roundX)
            {
                drawAlphaPixel(xpos     , ypos      , (1 - xA)              , c);
                drawAlphaPixel(xpos + 1 , ypos      , xA                    , c);
            }
            else if (roundX && roundY)
            {
                setPixel32(xpos , ypos  , c);
            }
        }

        /**
        * Draw an alpha32 pixel
        */
        private function drawAlphaPixel ( x:int, y:int, a:Number, c:Number, bg : int = -1 ):void
        {   
            //var g:uint = getPixel32(x,y);
            var g : int = 0xff000000;

            var r0:uint = ((g & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
            var g0:uint = ((g & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
            var b0:uint = ((g & 0x000000FF));

            var r1:uint = ((c & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
            var g1:uint = ((c & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
            var b1:uint = ((c & 0x000000FF));

            var ac:Number = 0xFF;
            var rc:Number = r1*a+r0*(1-a);
            var gc:Number = g1*a+g0*(1-a);
            var bc:Number = b1*a+b0*(1-a);

            var n:uint = (ac<<24)+(rc<<16)+(gc<<8)+bc;
            setPixel32(x,y,n);
        }

        /**
        * Check a triangle line
        */
        private function checkLine ( o:Array, x:int, y:int, c:int, r:Rectangle ):void
        {
            if (o[y])
            {
                if (o[y]>x)
                {
                    r.width=o[y]-x;
                    r.x=x;
                    r.y=y;
                    fillRect(r,c);
                }else
                {
                    r.width=x-o[y];
                    r.x=o[y];
                    r.y=y;
                    fillRect(r,c);
                }
            }else
            {
                o[y]=x;
            }
        }

        /**
        * Special line for filled triangle
        */
        private function lineTri ( o:Array, x0:int, y0:int, x1:int, y1:int, c:Number ):void
        {
            var steep:Boolean= (y1-y0)*(y1-y0) > (x1-x0)*(x1-x0);
            var swap:int;

            if (steep)
            {
                swap=x0; x0=y0; y0=swap;
                swap=x1; x1=y1; y1=swap;
            }

            if (x0>x1)
            {
                x0^=x1; x1^=x0; x0^=x1;
                y0^=y1; y1^=y0; y0^=y1;
            }

            var deltax:int = x1 - x0
            var deltay:int = (y1 - y0) < 0 ? -(y1 - y0) : (y1 - y0);
            var error:int = 0;
            var y:int = y0;         
            var ystep:int = y0<y1 ? 1 : -1;
            var x:int = x0;
            var xend:int = x1-(deltax>>1);
            var fx:int = x1;
            var fy:int = y1;
            var px:int = 0;
            r.x = 0;
            r.y = 0;
            r.width = 0;
            r.height = 1;

            while (x++<=xend)
            {
                if (steep)
                {
                    checkLine(o,y,x,c,r);
                    if (fx != x1 && fx != xend)
                        checkLine(o,fy,fx+1,c,r);
                }

                error += deltay;
                if ((error<<1) >= deltax)
                {
                    if (!steep)
                    {
                        checkLine(o,x-px+1,y,c,r);
                        if (fx!=xend) 
                            checkLine(o,fx+1,fy,c,r);
                    }
                    px = 0;
                    y += ystep;
                    fy -= ystep;
                    error -= deltax; 
                }
                px++;
                fx--;
            }

            if (!steep)
                checkLine(o,x-px+1,y,c,r);
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like just a typo or copy/paste error. The import statement should not be repeated inside your class definition:

```
package views 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import views.Canvas.Raster; // Yes
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Arthur Wulf White
     */
    public class RasterView extends Bitmap
    {   
        import views.Canvas.Raster // No
```

Also, avoid having an accessor with the same name as a class:

```
    public function get Raster():Raster  // Call this function get MyRaster or similar
    {
        return Raster(bitmapData);
    }
```

Code highlighting is your friend. Any time a property or function name other than your constructor lights up in Cyan, it means you're using an existing class name, which may cause problems.

Comment: You my friend are awesome, I can tell you actually looked at the code and took the time to help and highly appreciate it.

Comment: I truly owe you a debt of gratitude. I get it now, a Class is an object, so I had one object of type class named Raster and another object of type function also named Raster. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Aw, shucks... Repay me by answering somebody else's queries, when you can.